# Get column data sum from FormIO table element

Tags: javascript, formio, column-sum

I'm trying to get the column number sum in a table element from FormIO. At the moment I'm doing this with this script:

```
if(data['personesAtesesNoBinari17'] >= 0 || 
  data['personesAtesesNoBinari1631'] >= 0 || 
  data['personesAtesesNoBinari3066'] >= 0 || 
  data['personesAtesesNoBinari67'] >= 0){
  
if(data['personesAtesesNoBinari17'] === undefined){
    data['personesAtesesNoBinari17'] = 0;
  }
  if(data['personesAtesesNoBinari1631'] === undefined){
    data['personesAtesesNoBinari1631'] = 0;
  }
  if(data['personesAtesesNoBinari3066'] === undefined){
    data['personesAtesesNoBinari3066'] = 0;
  }
  if(data['personesAtesesNoBinari67'] === undefined){
    data['personesAtesesNoBinari67'] = 0;
  }
  data['personesAtesesNoBinariTotal2'] = 
    data['personesAtesesNoBinari17'] +
    data['personesAtesesNoBinari1631'] + 
    data['personesAtesesNoBinari3066'] + 
    data['personesAtesesNoBinari67'];

}else{
  data['personesAtesesNoBinariTotal2'] = 0;
}
```

> Each `data['']` is a cell with a number except the output: `data['personesAtesesVoluntariatTotal1']`.

As you can see, the code it is not clean but is the only way I can get the sum.
I've try this code too but it wont work in FormIO while in visual studio code works fine:

```
let result = 0;

for (let i = 1; i < (data['tableName'].rows.length-1); i++)
{
        result += parseInt(data['tableName'].rows[i].cells[1]);
}
data['outputName'] = result;
```

This is the JSON from the table:

```
{
  "label": "Table",
  "cellAlignment": "left",
  "customClass": "standardTable tableSpacing",
  "bordered": true,
  "hover": true,
  "key": "table22",
  "type": "table",
  "numRows": 6,
  "numCols": 4,
  "input": false,
  "tableView": false,
  "rows": [
    [
      {
        "components": []
      },
      {
        "components": [
          {
            "label": "HTML",
            "attrs": [
              {
                "attr": "",
                "value": ""
              }
            ],
            "content": "<div style=\"text-align:center ; background-color : #900000 ; height: 100%;\"><h3 style=\"color:white;font-weight: bold;\">No binari</h3></div>",
            "refreshOnChange": false,
            "key": "html154",
            "type": "htmlelement",
            "input": false,
            "tableView": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "components": [
          {
            "label": "HTML",
            "attrs": [
              {
                "attr": "",
                "value": ""
              }
            ],
            "content": "<div>Persones de menys de 16 anys</div>",
            "refreshOnChange": false,
            "key": "html155",
            "type": "htmlelement",
            "input": false,
            "tableView": false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "components": [
          {
            "label": "Number",
            "hideLabel": true,
            "mask": false,
            "tableView": false,
            "delimiter": false,
            "requireDecimal": false,
            "inputFormat": "plain",
            "truncateMultipleSpaces": false,
            "key": "personesAtesesNoBinari17",
            "type": "number",
            "input": true
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "components": [
          {
            "label": "HTML",
            "attrs": [
              {
                "attr": "",
                "value": ""
              }
            ],
            "content": "<div>Persones entre 16 a 29 anys</div>",
            "refreshOnChange": false,
            "key": "html156",
            "type": "htmlelement",
            "input": false,
            "tableView": false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "components": [
          {
            "label": "Number",
            "hideLabel": true,
            "mask": false,
            "tableView": false,
            "delimiter": false,
            "requireDecimal": false,
            "inputFormat": "plain",
            "truncateMultipleSpaces": false,
            "key": "personesAtesesNoBinari1631",
            "type": "number",
            "input": true
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "components": [
          {
            "label": "HTML",
            "attrs": [
              {
                "attr": "",
                "value": ""
              }
            ],
            "content": "<div>Persones entre 30 i 64 anys</div>",
            "refreshOnChange": false,
            "key": "html157",
            "type": "htmlelement",
            "input": false,
            "tableView": false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "components": [
          {
            "label": "Number",
            "hideLabel": true,
            "mask": false,
            "tableView": false,
            "delimiter": false,
            "requireDecimal": false,
            "inputFormat": "plain",
            "truncateMultipleSpaces": false,
            "key": "personesAtesesNoBinari3066",
            "type": "number",
            "input": true
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "components": [
          {
            "label": "HTML",
            "attrs": [
              {
                "attr": "",
                "value": ""
              }
            ],
            "content": "<div>Persones de 65 anys o més</div>",
            "refreshOnChange": false,
            "key": "html158",
            "type": "htmlelement",
            "input": false,
            "tableView": false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "components": [
          {
            "label": "Number",
            "hideLabel": true,
            "mask": false,
            "tableView": false,
            "delimiter": false,
            "requireDecimal": false,
            "inputFormat": "plain",
            "truncateMultipleSpaces": false,
            "key": "personesAtesesNoBinari67",
            "type": "number",
            "input": true
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "components": [
          {
            "label": "HTML",
            "attrs": [
              {
                "attr": "",
                "value": ""
              }
            ],
            "content": "<div>Total</div>",
            "refreshOnChange": false,
            "key": "html159",
            "type": "htmlelement",
            "input": false,
            "tableView": false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "components": [
          {
            "label": "Number",
            "hideLabel": true,
            "mask": false,
            "disabled": true,
            "tableView": false,
            "defaultValue": 0,
            "delimiter": false,
            "requireDecimal": false,
            "inputFormat": "plain",
            "truncateMultipleSpaces": false,
            "key": "personesAtesesNoBinariTotal2",
            "logic": [
              {
                "name": "SumatoriPersonesAtesesNoBinariTotal",
                "trigger": {
                  "type": "javascript",
                  "javascript": "if(data['personesAtesesNoBinari17'] >= 0 || data['personesAtesesNoBinari1631'] >= 0 || data['personesAtesesNoBinari3066'] >= 0 || data['personesAtesesNoBinari67'] >= 0){\n  if(data['personesAtesesNoBinari17'] === undefined){\n    data['personesAtesesNoBinari17'] = 0;\n  }\n  if(data['personesAtesesNoBinari1631'] === undefined){\n    data['personesAtesesNoBinari1631'] = 0;\n  }\n  if(data['personesAtesesNoBinari3066'] === undefined){\n    data['personesAtesesNoBinari3066'] = 0;\n  }\n  if(data['personesAtesesNoBinari67'] === undefined){\n    data['personesAtesesNoBinari67'] = 0;\n  }\n  data['personesAtesesNoBinariTotal2'] = data['personesAtesesNoBinari17'] + data['personesAtesesNoBinari1631'] + data['personesAtesesNoBinari3066'] + data['personesAtesesNoBinari67'];\n}else{\n  data['personesAtesesNoBinariTotal2'] = 0;\n}"
                },
                "actions": [
                  {
                    "name": "SumatoriPersonesAtesesNoBinariTotal",
                    "type": "value",
                    "value": "value = data['personesAtesesNoBinariTotal2'];"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "type": "number",
            "personesAtesesNoBinariTotal2": 0,
            "personesAtesesNoBinariTotal": 0,
            "input": true
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your question. Can you provide a [minimally reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via a JSFiddle or even just your form's JSON so we can have a better idea of what you're trying to do? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @BrendanBond. Thanks for comment. I've add the JSON and change the logic example with a shorter one so It could be readed easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Rather than use custom logic here, I'd use the [calculated value](https://help.form.io/developers/form-evaluations#calculated-value) field, which is much more in line with what you're trying to accomplish. Check out [this working example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brendanbond/p9tLzmsf/5/).
2. The table component is an older component more geared towards layout concerns and is less ergonomic when making calculations like this (as you can see from the code above, where I have to double check that the `personesAtesesNoBinariTotal2` key is not being counted towards the total value). The data grid component is much more suited for this kind of  thing, check out [this working example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brendanbond/8ozu3e2f/6/). The code to calculate this value is much more in line how you expected your for loop to work:

   ```
   value = data.expenses.reduce(function(total, row) {
     return total + row.amount;
   }, 0);
   ```

   which could easily be written as:

   ```
   for (let row of data.expenses) {
     value += row.amount;
   }
   ```

Comment: I've found this very useful but with data grids as you say. I'm trying to use calculated value on the table but It won't work... I must use tables because users can't edit forms and make a table with an edit grid or data grid is not that easy. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Javi What about the first JSFiddle isn't working? That uses your table

Comment: OH WOW I linked the wrong thing, I've fixed that first JSFiddle link @Javi

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to mention about the link... what a mess... Thank you so much @BrendanBond , works fine!!

Comment: Hi again @BrendanBond. Despite the fact that your solution works, sometimes it fails to do the sum correctly. In some tables, if I set a 1 in the first input and another 1 in the second input, the total adds up to 32 (1+1 = 32). Would you know why this is? Also, how could be the script to sum specific fields and not the whole table? If you think this deserves another question, tell me and I'll create a new one. Thanks.

Comment: @Javi yeah might be best to start fresh in another question

Comment: Hi @BrendanBond. This is the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75148537/problem-with-table-data-sum-in-formio-table-element